# Rails on Mac - rake db:create error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I installed RVM and rails on my MAC (`Mavericks 10.9.1`) and I try to run rake db:create. However I constantly get this error:

```
 MacBook-Pro-Szymon:wybierzto Fengson$ rake db:create
    rake aborted!
    dlopen(/Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    /Users/Fengson/UJ/ProjektZespolowy/wybierzto/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Fengson/UJ/ProjektZespolowy/wybierzto/Rakefile:4:in `require'
    /Users/Fengson/UJ/ProjektZespolowy/wybierzto/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /Users/Fengson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Also, how can I properly install MySQL Server so that I can set a default password? It asked me for a password on Windows machine but here it didn't when I was installing `MySQL5 + server`. Thanks!

Comment: How did you install mysql? Perhaps the MySQL installer or with homebrew?

Comment: homebrew. Then I installed from an installer. Still, nothing.
I am installing it all again, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reinstall `mysql` through homebrew. and reinstall `mysql` gem

 `gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config path/to/mysql_config`